# CSS positioning alignment when drawing line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a simple [**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/reposeyu/2/edit) to draw a line between 2 points. ( *no drawing libraries. just js/jq*).

I have already have the code which calculates the angle ( I took it from [this](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples) library).

so it looks like this :

[image]

When I drag the **right bottom** circle ( *I added jquery draggable*) it all looks good.
Why it looks good ?

becuase the code of origin-transform is : `top left`

```
$("#line") .width(...)
           .css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + angle  + 'deg)')
           .css('-webkit-transform-origin','top left').
```

So the div's (red line actually) rotation axis is the `top left` point.

**Great.**

So where is the problem ?

It starts when I mess with the `left top` circle... here - I dont know how to deal with the red line position...

[image]

- How can I fix my code in `-webkit-transform-origin` in order to support both changes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot to set the left offset for the line:

Add

```
.css('left',x2+10)
```

(and change `.css('top',$('#box2').offset().top+10)` to `.css('left',y2+10)`)

and everything will work fine:

[Your modified example](http://jsbin.com/reposeyu/8/edit) - now with correct start;)

Comment: @NathanLee Yes I know I have all the cross browser transofrmation including ms's `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix`.... tnx

Comment: @RoyiNamir You are welcome, just call `g()` once in the beginning to have the correct initial state (see edited example). Also, replace the offsets with the already calculated values `x2` and `y2`.